# VC11 LNK1107 referencing a header file

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

So I've looked for almost 2 days now for a solution to my problem, but everyone else getting this error seems to be linking against a dll instead of a lib. However, that doesn't seem to be the case for me, so here I am.

I'm trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2012 using the vc110 (VS2012) toolchain. However, whenever I build the project, I get the following linker error from the build log (detailed verbosity):

```
1>Task "Link"
1>  Environment Variables passed to tool:
1>    VS_UNICODE_OUTPUT=1344
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:S:\twk_amf\Implementation\EditorServiceMgr\proj\Win\vc9\..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\..\..\..\..\..\..\external\Trolltech_Qt4\lib\win\x64\Debug msvcrtd.lib QtCored4.lib QtGuid4.lib QtXmld4.lib QtNetworkd4.lib QtUiToolsd.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB /NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcp.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libci.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcid.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcimt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcimtd.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.lib" /MACHINE:X64 ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.h
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.rc
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.res
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.dll
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.res
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.obj
1>  Tracking command:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe /a /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll /i S:\twk_results_win\ViewLocal\x64\MC_inter\EditorServiceMgr\Debug /r "S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_INTER\EDITORSERVICEMGR\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGR.RES|S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_INTER\EDITORSERVICEMGR\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGRSVC.H|S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_INTER\EDITORSERVICEMGR\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGRSVC.OBJ|S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_INTER\EDITORSERVICEMGR\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGRSVC.RC|S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_INTER\EDITORSERVICEMGR\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGRSVC.RES|S:\TWK_RESULTS_WIN\VIEWLOCAL\X64\MC_OUT\DEBUG\EDITORSERVICEMGRSVC.DLL" /b MSBuildConsole_CancelEvent31ad2214810446c299127f83382c747d  /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe"  /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:S:\twk_amf\Implementation\EditorServiceMgr\proj\Win\vc9\..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\..\..\..\..\..\..\external\Trolltech_Qt4\lib\win\x64\Debug msvcrtd.lib QtCored4.lib QtGuid4.lib QtXmld4.lib QtNetworkd4.lib QtUiToolsd.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB /NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcp.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libci.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcid.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcimt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcimtd.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.lib" /MACHINE:X64 ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.h
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.rc
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.res
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_out/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.dll
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgr.res
1>  ..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.obj
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\twk_results_win/ViewLocal/x64/MC_inter/EditorServiceMgr/Debug\EditorServiceMgrSvc.h : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x5F2
1>  The command exited with code 1107.
1>Done executing task "Link" -- FAILED.
```

From the build output, I thought that the linker might be trying to link against a header file, but I haven't been able to find any evidence of that.

The file referenced here, `EditorServiceMgrSvc.h`, only contains macro definitions, no includes. The header file is also referenced in the rc file, and is included as a symbol header file. Furthermore, there are only libs within the additional dependencies of the project's property pages.

I will put up what I can in addition to the build output, if needed, but I may not be able to put up that much since I'm working on proprietary code. Any ideas of what's happening here?

**EDIT:**
Note that this project was auto-converted from Visual Studio 2008 project format.

Comment: I guess you've already read this, but linking just in case you haven't: [Linker Tools Error LNK1107](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately both cases don't seem to apply.

Comment: The build output definitely says that you're trying to link a header file.  Can you double-check your project and its settings?

Comment: I checked the project properties, and there isn't a single linker option that included a header file.